# Extracting data from other websites (not illegal)

Tags: php, jquery, html, web, live

I am creating a football transfer site and i want to know how to extract particular pieces of data from a site and insert it into mine. For example, this site : http://www.footballtransferleague.co.uk/football_rumours.aspx , shows you transfer rumours and I want to insert them into my site however they update every 24 hours so I want the new data to appear on my site aswell.

Im not asking for any code, just some tips or videos that can be used to learn about this.

Before anyone says this is illegal, football rumours are considered as 'facts' hence available to reuse.

thanks in advance !

Comment: There's a difference between having the same facts and plagiarism. Isn't rumours by definition not a facts?

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.I would suggest that you find a development forum (perhaps [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/)?) to work out generalities. Then, when you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try with this tool. It downloads the pages with the code that is only translated like html, js and sometimes php. i don't know if it works with .asp .aspx.

[htttrack](https://www.httrack.com/)